# Display a SQL request on a partial page not a view Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have a laravel layout which have "partials pages". 
I call them in the layout by using includes :

```
@include('admin.partials.nav')
```

My issue is that I have to put in the nav page an SQL result on each page that use this navigation.

For this i created a method in a specific class named UtilsClass :

class UtilsController extends Controller
{

```
public function vcList(){
    $valuechainLists = Valuechain::select('valuechains.id', 'lang_valuechain.vcname', 'lang_valuechain.vcshortname')
        ->join('lang_valuechain', 'valuechains.id', '=', 'lang_valuechain.valuechain_id')
        ->join('langs', 'lang_valuechain.lang_id', '=', 'langs.id')
        ->where('langs.isMainlanguage', '=', '1')
        ->whereNull('valuechains.deleted_at')
        ->get();

    return $valuechainLists;
}
```

}

Now my issue is the following :

- How to get the return of this request on each method that is returning a view that uses the layout which uses this navigation ?
- How do i pass the array from this method to other methods in other classes ? Do i have to add something like this : use App\Http\Controllers\BackOffice\UtilsController in the class that would use the concerned layout ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a View Composer for that.

There is a tutorial about that [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/sharing-data-between-views-using-laravel-view-composers)

You can also check out more information [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers) in the Laravel docs